# React MaterialTable v1 not displaying pagination if number of rows is less than default

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have a table setup using react MaterialTable 1.6.2 If I have less than the default starting number of rows the pagination options do not appear at the bottom. I would still like them to appear for consistency's sake (eg one table has no pagination options, then change categories and the next table has pagination). Ive looked through the relevant docs, but dont see a way to force pagination to appear: https://v1.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/pagination#pagination-feature-guide

```
        <MaterialTable
          data={this.state.rows}
          columns={this.state.columns}
          options={{ 
            showTitle: false,
            pageSizeOptions:[25,50,100,200,500,1000],
            pageSize:25,
            /* like excel freeze col
          fixedColumns: {
              left: 1, 
              right: 0
            }
            */
          }}
          localization={{
            header: {
                actions: 'Edit/Delete'
            },
            body: {
                emptyDataSourceMessage: 'No records to display',
                filterRow: {
                    filterTooltip: 'Filter'
                }
            }
          }}
          .........
```